# Generate table using pdf package in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-generation

I need generate a pdf file with table as image [image]

I am using pdf package [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) but I still don't know how to create a table. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Here my code:

```
Table table = Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(width: 0.75),
      children: [
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text("Number order"),
            Text("Name"),
            //...
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Did you find  solution?
@DongPhamBK?

Comment: Yes, you can use many row and column for table!